# How to update object onClick in Rect?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object

I'm trying to make vote system, but unfortunetly i can't make to update vote value with every click? It's working only once. Data is from data.json file.

```
  const [vote, setVote] = useState<number>(props.score);

  const voteUp = () => {
    setVote(props.score + 1);
  };

  const voteDown = () => {
    setVote(props.score - 1);
  };

  return (
    <CommentStyled key={props.id}>
      <div>
        <CommentScore>
          <VoteButtonStyled onClick={voteUp}>
            <img src={IconPlus} alt="IconPlus" />
          </VoteButtonStyled>
          {vote}
          <VoteButtonStyled onClick={voteDown}>
            <img src={IconMinus} alt="IconMinus" />
          </VoteButtonStyled>
        </CommentScore>
      </div>
```

Here's my project on github: https://github.com/xflameyoke/interactive-comment-section-app

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue. You may be able to use [Stack Snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537) to provide a runnable example here; otherwise there are a number of services that provide similar experiences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating based on props.score, which is propably fixed. Update based on the vote instead:

```
const voteUp = () => {
    setVote(lastVote => lastVote + 1);
 };

const voteDown = () => {
    setVote(lastVote => lastVote - 1);
};
```